# Web Forms Authentication from code-behind

Tags: asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

Within my application a privileged user can add/delete/update user roles (while also assigning them to specific users). The below excerpt shows a rule in my web.config file which allows the functionality of user blocking to only administrators:

```
<location path="block-user.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="Administrator"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

What if I want to dynamically add or delete other roles besides the default one? Can this be done through code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict some pages to certain roles, you can do this in Page_Load function;

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if(!User.IsInRole(allowedrole))
          {
             Response.Redirect("block-user.aspx");
          }
          else
          {
          //do stuff
          }
    }
```